# ExtJS MVC application customized location parameters

Tags: extjs, model-view-controller, extjs4.2

Is it possible to load store/model/view with custom parameters?
I have structure like this:

```
- app/
- app/store/mystore.js
- app/model/mymodel.js
- app/view/myview.js
- app.js
- index.html
```

app.js content

```
Ext.application({
models: [
    'mymodel'
],
stores: [
    'mystore'
],
views: [
    'mystore'
],
...
```

Browser loads those 3 files like this:
`http://localhost/myapp/app/store/mystore.js`
Is it possible to load them somehow with extra params like this: `http://localhost/myapp/app/store/mystore.js?myparam=foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You cannot do it separate per file!

But there are at least two ways to archive it:
You could either override the `loadScript` and `loadScriptFile` to modify the `url` or always use `disableCaching: true` and modify the `disableCachingParam` like so `myparam=foo&_dc`

Now each file would be loaded like

```
http://localhost/myapp/app/store/mystore.js?myparam=foo&_dc=3242423423
http://localhost/myapp/app/model/mymodel.js?myparam=foo&_dc=3242423434
http://localhost/myapp/app/view/myview.js?myparam=foo&_dc=3242423489
```

Comment: `Ext.Loader.loadScript` solved my case. Defining model and view in loadScript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `routes`? There is a module which you can download from :

[Ext.ux.Router](https://market.sencha.com/extensions/ext-ux-router)

Comment: Seems intersting. How you would configure applications routes so that you app url is ends like this: `myapp/index.html?foo=bar` and i want that `foo=bar` will be added to view file that app loads. View name is `myview`. something like this `myapp/myview.js?foo=bar`

Comment: Dear Tilt, have you check out example? There is a small app like your request. Basically, you can call view by `'mycontroller/:foo/bar' : mystore#foo` which is `mystore` is your view.